# importing sub-modules in python

Tags: python, flask

I'm playing around with Python/Flask and loosely [following this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications#step-5-set-up-the-application-in-%E2%80%9Capp-init-py%E2%80%9D) on how to structure "large" apps. I linked to the part i'm having trouble with.

i have the following setup:

```
/project
  /app
    __init__.py
    /mod_users
      __init_.py
      controllers.py
      models.py
  requirements.txt
```

My `/project/app/__init__.py` looks like this.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='postgresql://localhost/python_app',
    SECRET_KEY='development key',
    USERNAME='davidadams',
    PASSWORD=''
))

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from .mod_users.controllers import mod_users

app.register_blueprint(mod_users)

db.create_all()
```

I'm referencing the `mod_users` package relatively. This works but it's not like how the guide looks. If i change it to how the guide has it, i get a module not found error.

```
app.mod_users.controllers import mod_users
```

Did i miss a step somewhere to make this work? Is the guide wrong?

I'm using `export FLASK_APP=app && flask run` to run the app if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I miss a step somewhere to make this work? Is the guide wrong?

*The workaround you did is correct. But you did more than the guide.*

---

The guide does not mention anything about **running flask in CLI**

Following the document, the largeapp will run by run.py.

**folder structure**

```
/project
  run.py
  /app
    __init__.py
    /mod_users
```

**run.py**

```
from app import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

**Note: The path of `mod_user` could be both**

```
from mod_users.controllers import mod_users
from app.mod_users.controllers import mod_users
```

**Then run by following command**

```
python run.py
```

---

> To run flask in CLI by command `export FLASK_APP=app && flask run`

Because you have exported the path, few things need to be changed.

**1. the path of mod_user could ONLY be**

```
from mod_users.controllers import mod_users
```

**New folder directory**

```
/project
                #2. Do not need `run.py` anymore
  /app
    app.py      #3. Rename `app/__init__.py` into `app/app.py`
    /mod_users
```

Comment: Are flask apps expected to be run with the flask cli command in production? If not, why does it exist if you'd have to change your imports in production?

Comment: Yes. [Here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/326517/why-is-flask-cli-recommended-over-flask-run) is the explanation. Quote the most important sentence: *The reason for this is that due to how the reload mechanism works there are some bizarre side-effects*

Comment: Reloading is for development though. Everything i'm reading suggests that the cli tool is strictly for development. I don't see any mention of using the cli tool to [deploy to self-hosted](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/#self-hosted-options) production environments.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your question. If you want to make a flask application in production mode, you will use neither `flask run` nor `python run.py`. Because of the performance consideration, not like node js which running natively, flask will use `uwsgi on apache/nginx/etc` in production mode.

Comment: When using uwsgi, the project will need an additional file which is called `uwsgi.py`. It will run by uwsgi(program) on certain port. Webserver will redirect that port into regular port(or you can assign a custom port). In this architecture, the socket performance will be handled by webserver/wsgi_mod rather than flask application itself.

Comment: let me ask it this way...how should i reference sub-modules if i want to use flask cli for development and not have to change my imports when i use uwsgi in production? should i just always reference packages relatively? That seems to work in both cases.

Comment: In general, there is no obligation. `wsgi.py` can import the flask application from the file contains `xxx=Flask(...)`. However, we have known flask cli is suggested based on the reference of second comment. Therefore, for making production and development consistent in that case, using my second solution in development and writing `from app import your_flask_app` in your `wsgi.py` for production is match for your purpose.